# Splitting an array gives me is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like this:

```
0: ["-22.91401497538739,-68.19866465000001"]
1: ["-25.857842171488155,-54.4140132"]
2: ["-33.39697196046993,-70.79329520000005"]
3: ["-34.61587176137625,-58.433298449999995"]
4: ["-34.92952451109041,138.59812584999997"]
5: ["14.841,-89.156"]
```

I need to split each value so I do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < coordsB.length; i++) {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordsB[i].split(','));
```

But I get:

> ```
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: coordsB[i].split is not a function
> ```

Full code:

```
    function externalContent() {
      fetch("https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=50&status=publish", {
        headers: { 
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
      }).then(function(response) { 
        return response.json(); 
      }).then(function(data) {
        coordsB = [];
        var externaldates = data.map(x=> x["data"]);
        externaldates = $.grep(externaldates, function(n){ return (n); });
        $.unique(externaldates.sort());
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
          coordsB.push(data[i]["usp-custom-90"]["usp-custom-90"]);
        });
        coordsB = $.grep(coordsB, function(n){ return (n); });
        $.unique(coordsB.sort());
        for (var i = 0; i < coordsB.length; i++) {
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordsB[i].split(','));
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            linkToPost: externaldates[i]
          }),
          circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            radius: 1.1,
            fillColor: '#ff007f',
            strokeColor: '#ff007f',
            strokeOpacity: 0.75,
            strokeWeight: 20,
            linkToPost: links[i],
            longitude: longitude[i],
            latitude: latitude[i]
          });
          circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
          circle.bindTo('map', marker, 'map');
          markers.push(marker);
          marker.setVisible(false);

          google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'click', function() {
            $("#map").css("display", "none");
            $(".loader").css("display", "flex");
            $("body").css("background", "black");
            $(".flex-shrink-0").addClass("send");
            $("#longiTude").attr("value", this.longitude);
            $("#latiTude").attr("value", this.latitude);
            $("#timeSearch").attr("action", this.linkToPost);
            window.location.href = this.linkToPost;
          });
        }

      });
    }
```

Comment: try `coordsB[i][0].split(',')` as it looks like a list of lists, so you want to get the string from the list

Comment: @depperm yup, thanks. If you put that into an answer I'LL accept it

Comment: You can close it since it is just a typo and adds no long term value to the site

Comment: @adiga I thought about it, yet it is not a typo, it is a wrong way how I was targetting an object, might still be useful

Comment: I meant typo as a closing reason: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers"*

Comment: @adiga but that's not correct, I was targeting `coordsB[i].split(',')` while I should have targeted `coordsB[i][0].split(',')` and that's a mistake, isn't about something which cannot be reproduced anymore or a typo at all: The accepted answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to call `coordsB[i][0].split(',')` as `coordsB` is a list of lists